# How to apply style in module in Moodle

Tags: css, moodle

How can I add style to module. I tried like this..

I added a new plugin called `sample` in **mod** folder. In **view.php** i have a `div`

```
echo html_writer::div('its here', 'demo');
```

I have to apply style for this `div`.
What i did is.. I am using **theme** `clean`. In `config.php` inside the **theme/clean** I add

```
$THEME->modsheets = true;
```

And I create `styles.css` inside the  **sample** folder. The `styles.css` contain

```
.demo
{
color:red;
}
```

But unfortunately nothing happened..I have to apply style for this module. How can I do this..Please help..

**Note**: I am using `Moodle 2.7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that should work, but Moodle's caching is pretty aggressive so clearing the browser cache often isn't enough to see the results of a theme update.

I suspect you need to either purge your caches (at /admin/purgecaches.php) or switch on theme designer mode (at /admin/settings.php?section=themesettings) which effectively turns off CSS caching.